# With vcpkg portfile, how to insert regular CMake command?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to customize a lib installed through vcpkg with regular CMake commands.
The only thing I need to tweak is to enable a preprocessor, e.g., BUILD_WITH_THIS_OPTINAL_FEATURE.

With Visual Studio, it's pretty straightforward: Just add it to the `C/C++ > Preprocessor` property of the project. But with vcpkg, it's unclear how to mix it with its own functions.

Say if I have a portfile ready under

```sh
E:\_dev\vcpkg\ports\mylib\portfile.cmake
```

I'd really love to let it know that I want to

```sh
add_compile_definitions(BUILD_WITH_THIS_OPTINAL_FEATURE)
```

But doing so directly in `portfile.cmake` gives me

```sh
CMake Error at ports/mylib/portfile.cmake:38 (add_compile_definitions):
  Unknown CMake command "add_compile_definitions".
```

Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself.

I just need to add the following to `vcpkg_configure_cmake`'s `OPTIONS` input arg

```
-DBUILD_WITH_THIS_OPTINAL_FEATURE=ON
```